# Open a img from an anchor tag embeded inside webbrowser control through HTML templet

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am having a winform webbrowser control. I am embedding HTML table having some placeholders like-

```
<tr style="{{BCColor}}">
<td><font size="2">{{TestCaseName}} </font></td>
<td><font size="2">{{TestCaseStatus}}<a href="file:///D:/IMG/MyPic.jpg" target="_blank">Download</a></font></td>
```

I am binding this HTML template from C#. Clicking on anchor tag not opening anything but when if I replace href with bing url(http://www.bing.com) it is opening a new page. No image or elsx file is opening from clicking on anchor tag.

Comment: When you inspect, is the image path showing in the href= attribute?  That's where I would start troubleshooting.

Comment: Yeah, it is having a right path. When I right click and save target as, image is saving in local drive.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't work.  Can you past your generated markup?  Also, I wouldn't use <font> anymore.  Set the text styles through CSS.  Put a <span> around your text where you want the font changed and give it a class.  <span class="some-class">text</span> and in your css .some-class {font-size=23px;}/*or whatever you want*/